# Prove that $3$ divides $14^{2n}-1$ with modular arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Like the title says. I know how I would go about solving this with a proof by induction method, but since they ask me to do it with modular arithmetic I'm lost.

I changed it to:
$14^{2n}-1  \cong 0\pmod 3$

And tried to solve it in some way but failed.

Edit: I forgot the -1

Comment: It isn't true even for $n=1.$ Do you perhaps mean $14^{2n}-1$?

Comment: If you factorize 14 you get $(2^17^1)^{2n}$ which is not divisible for 3

Comment: Note that $14^{2n}=(15-1)^{2n}\equiv (0-1)^{2n}\equiv (-1)^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod 3$

Comment: For any $m$ not a multiple of $3$, $m^{2n}{-}1$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to follow the trend and assume you want $14^{2n}-1$ to be divisible by $3$. Then we know

$$  14 \equiv 2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$$

(To check this, just divide $14$ by $3$ and look at the remainder.)

Thus

$$14^{2n}-1 \equiv (-1)^{2n}-1 \equiv ((-1)^2)^n-1 \equiv 1^n-1 \equiv 1-1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the question reads

$$
14^{2n}-1 \equiv 0 \mod 3
$$

we have

$$
(1-15)^{2n}-1= 1-(-1)-(2n)15+(2n)(2n-1)\frac{15^2}{2!}+\cdots = 15k
$$

Answer (score 0):

$3$ does not divide $14$, and so does not divide $14^n$.

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $14^{2n} = (14^n)^2\equiv 1 \bmod 3$. Thus $3$ divides $14^{2n}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$14=15-1 ⇒ 14^{2n}-1=(15-1)^{2n}-1==15 m +1 -1=15 m$